# Lotto code,the previous number cannot appear again,how do i improve it

Tags: matlab, random

I use matlab to write this code,and it seems there is something wrong with logic,but i don't know where am i wrong and how to improve this.

i want to write a lotto code,and there are six numbers in it,the range of first six numbers is 1 to 38,the range of last number is 1 to 8.Here is my code

```
previous_number=randi([1,38],1,6)
last=randi([1,8],1,1) %produce the last number

for k =1:6    
    while  last== previous_number %while that last number is the same as the value of one of the previous number
    last=randi([1,8],1,1)%then produce the last number again,until the different value produce
    end
end
ltto=[previous_number last]
```

but i found that the last number will still generate the same number as the first six numbers,for example,

"1"  2 33 55 66 10  "1"

1 "2" 33 55 66 10  "2"
Why?i have already said

```
while  last==previous_number(k)
    last=randi([1,8],1,1)
    end
```

if i want to write the code in c or other program language,i think i can just use if ,while and loop,etc,like this basic loop,i can't use the "ismemeber"or randperm. how can i rewrite the code?

if i rewrite as

```
previous_number=randi([1,38],1,6)
last=randi([1,8],1,1) %produce the last number

for k =1:6    
    if  last== previous_number(k) %while that last number is the same as the value of one of the previous number
    last=randi([1,8],1,1)%then produce the last number again,until the different value produce
    end
end
ltto=[previous_number last]
```

the result will also show me "1" 2 21 12 13 22 "1" sometimes

Comment: Don't use random tags

Comment: @Lightness: on the other hand, the [random] tag is justified. :D

Comment: @CrisLuengo Punctacular :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occures because you first iterate over the numbers, then replace `last` according to the specific current iteration, without regarding the previous ones.

For example, in your example data, think that `last = 10` so you get to the sixth iteration, find that `last` is equal to `b(k)` that is 10, so you replace it. But now it can generate `1`, and you will finish the while loop and the for loop.

**The solution is** to compare `last` to all your vector, not iterate over it:

```
previous_number = b(1:6);
last = previous_number(1);
while ismember(last, previous_number)
    last = randi(8); %produce the last number
end
```

---

[As of comments discussion:]

If you still want to compare each element separately, you can do it like that:

```
previous_number=randi([1,38],1,6)
last=randi(8) 
k=0;

while k <= 5   
    k = k + 1;
    if last == previous_number(k)
        last = randi(8);
        k = 0;
    end
end
ltto=[previous_number last]
```

Comment: i am just a little confused about it,but i write 'while (last==previous(k))',isn't it mean when last == one of element in previous,doesn't it mean a "compare to all element in a vector"?If not ,i also use the " if " in stead of "while", it should  also have the compared meaning,but the result is the same as while

Comment: if i want to write the code in c or other program language,i think i can just use if ,while and loop,etc,like this basic loop,i can't use the ismemeber.how can i write the code?

Comment: `previous(k)` is scalar, not vector, so it can compare only to specific scalar. I don't know how C treats changing the iterator, but conceptually you should replace the `while` with `if`, and if it equal and you do generate a new random number, you have to return to the first element and start all the comparisons again, so inside the `if` insert also `k=1`

Comment: previous_number=randi([1,38],1,6)
    last=randi([1,8],1,1) %produce the last number
    
    for k =1:6    
        if  last== previous_number(k) %while that last number is the same as the value of one of the previous number
        last=randi([1,8],1,1)%then produce the last number again,until the different value produce
        end
    end
    ltto=[previous_number last]

the result will also show me "1" 2 21 12 13 22 "1" sometimes

Comment: i have edited the question but the result didn't become better

Comment: you should add `k=1` inside the `if`, after `last=randi...` . But you change the iterator, I don't sure it will work in matlab

Comment: A better idea- replace `for` with `while` and add `k=k+1` after the `if-end`. Then you can change the iterator inside the loop, and add `k=1` in case of producing new `last`

Comment: do you mean  
    if  last== previous_number(k) ,then k=1:6?

Comment: can you rewrite the code as you said to me? i think i can understand it easier

Comment: I added the full option to the answer

Comment: @蕭仰恩  `k <= 6` includes the option that k=6, it's ok.

Comment: but if that,k<=6,the window will show me Attempted to access previous_number(7); index out of bounds because numel(previous_number)=6.

Error in lotto_sol (line 7)
    if last == previous_number(k)